# changing the UITextField from ParseUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, parseui

I am using parseUI to login and signup to my app as it is very handy and easy with the existent users, forgot password and all others functionality however I use a custom class to UITextField through all my application that looks very different from the default ones.

I try to download the pod from ParseUI but I had lots of conflicts with the original parse libraries that were already in my project `"Apple Match-o duplication"`

So I delete all install parseUI pod and after I install the missing libs I need and I still having `"Apple Match-o Missing references"`

I think is because the open source of [`parseUI is 1.7.4`](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS) and the [`parselibs are 1.7.5.`](https://www.parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/latest)

My question is, is there anyway that I can change the `UITextField` used in parseUI to use my `customUITextField`?

**Note:** The app works fine since I am using ParseUI from 1.7.5 not from the openSource (where I can change the UITextField class)

I am doing it in swift but I am happy if you have any code in object-c or if there is a way to do it using the interface build.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had this error too! Are you sure you are copying the files to the right destination?

Comment: I am using pod so I didn't really manually copy any files the pod install did it for me. The app works fine since I am using ParseUI from 1.7.5 not from the openSource (where I can change the UITextField class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to import parseUI if anyone is have the same problem what I did was:

1. Drop all the frameworks in my project and close XCode
2. Added all the pods from Parse in my Podfile and run parse install

   pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1'

   pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.7'

   pod 'ParseCrashReporting', '~> 1.7'

   pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7'

It added all the pending framework for me end was everything working in the end with all the code I need!